# What do i do wrong in passing the parameters?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My function:

```
def buttons_for_country(main_master,datasets):
    country_list = every_country_in_datasets(datasets)
    rows = 0
    columns = 0
    for i in range(1,len(country_list)):
        name = "button",i
        name = tkinter.Button(master = main_master,
                             command = lambda: plot(10000)
                             height = 2,
                             width=10,
                             text=country_list[i-1])
        
        if rows == 12:
            rows = 0
            colums += 1

        name.grid(rows,columns)
        
        rows += 1
        name.pack()
```

It cames error at `name.grid(rows,columns)` said:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Python/Covid/Cov_predict.py", line 93, in <module>
    buttons_for_country(window,df)
  File "c:/Python/Covid/Cov_predict.py", line 75, in buttons_for_country
    name.grid(rows,columns)
TypeError: grid_configure() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

It seems fine with by giving 2 params `rows` and `columns`
But it said i given `3 params`
Where do i did wrong here?

Comment: Calling a method on an instance implicitly adds the positional argument `self` to the front of your arguments. Try `name.grid(row=rows, column=columns)`.

Comment: There are some additional problems here but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Axe319 yea it solved the problem , need to remove `name.pack()` and change typo from `colums += 1` to `columns += 1`..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the row and column as keyword arguments.

```
name.grid(row=rows, column=columns)
```

You also need to remove `name.pack()` - a widget can only be controlled by a single geometry manager, and the last one you use is the one that is in control. Calling `pack()` after calling `grid()` removes all of the benefits of calling `grid()`.